# Load camera in android

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, tablet

When i use this code camera load in my phone and simulator but when run this code in tablet project stopped.what's problem?

```
getPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does the stack trace say?  And does the tablet actually have a camera and a camera app?

Comment: every thing is ok in my phone and in simulator. i said it !!! in my tablet it's wrong.how i can trace it in tablet?!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Attach via usb. Turn on USB debugging. Run adb logcat in a terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as:

```
getPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                    ? new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE)
                    : new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});
```